# Possible to use WSL2 to build LFS

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, linux-from-scratch

I am wondering if it is possible for me to use Windows Subsystem Linux 2 (Windows Insider Fast Ring Update) to build a Linux From Scratch? What I am worried about is that I am unable to delete the partition made during the steps of the building my own Linux distro.
When I use lsblk command I see two partitions which are 256GB each which is my main disk. I am afraid of messing up and causing my machine to hang after I am done with the custom distro and wish to delete that partition.

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming questions only. Question may be suitable for [Superuser](http://superuser.com) but check their posting requirements in the help pages first.

Comment: Oh no ok, I will check on the posting requirements next time I post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In LFS Book, chapter [2.2. Host System Requirements](http://linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter02/hostreqs.html) you have all requirements listed. There is also listing of the script that automates package/version checking.

If your WSL2 meets LFS host requirements, then go for it! If not - it might be still possible to build something Linuxish, but process described in LFS Book will not work!